# For a group $G$ with subgroup $H$, can two different elements of $H$ be conjugated to the same $ i \in H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$N_{G}(H) :=  \{ g \in G $; $gHg^{-1}=H \} $.
I understand that this implies that for any $ h \in H,$ we have that $ghg^{-1} = i \in H $ where $i$ could possibly equal $h$. My question is, can two different elements of $H$, $h_{1} \neq h_{2}$ be conjugated to the same $ i \in H$, i.e $gh_{1}g^{-1} = gh_{2}g^{-1} = i$ ?

Comment: With the same $g$?  No, just cancel them.

Comment: The answer to the sentence *before* the i.e. is "yes". The answer to the question *after* the i.e. is "no". The difference is the altering of the $g$s. If you allow the $g$s to vary then, for example, if $g^{-1}hg=i$ then both $h$ and $i$ are conjugate to $i$ (here the conjugator is the trivial element).

Comment: Dear Derpp: "normalizer definition confusion" is a very bad choice of title for your question.  Not only is your question not about the definition, but also it doesn't help anybody to add the word "confusion."  I've changed it to be the question you asked, and in the future you should do something similar when possible.  Using bad titles drives people away from helping you, so it is in your best interest to make things as easy as possible. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb alright sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x\in H$, and any $g\in G$, there exists $h_x\in H$ such that $x=gh_xg^{-1}$, in particular, $h_x=g^{-1}xg\in H$.

What I'm saying is that *every* $x$ is a conjugate of *something* by *every* $g$.  That is no surprise.

But if you insist that two conjugates use the same $g$, then no, because conjugation is a 1-1 map. You can just cancel $g$ and its inverse to prove equality of the things sandwiched between.

Comment: ok yes thank you! i didn't know conjugation was an injective map. that clarifies a lot.

Comment: is conjugation a group action, i.e. a map from $(G \times H) \to H$?

Comment: @Derpp Most of the time we consider the group as acting on itself via conjugation, but yes, normal subgroups are stable under the action.

Answer (score 1):

If $gh_{1}g^{-1} = gh_{2}g^{-1}$, then $(g^{-1}g)h_1(g^{-1}g)=(g^{-1}g)h_2(g^{-1}g)$, *i.e.*, $h_1=h_2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You have $gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2 g^{-1}$ if and only if $h_1=h_2$, which follows directly from the cancellative property of groups (multiply on left and right by $g^{-1}$ and $g$)